# DevToolsClientImpl : subscribing a listener to the already connected DevToolsClient

Tags: selenium-webdriver, azure-pipelines

I'm setting up CI/CD Azure pipeline to run Selenium Test Automation scripts using Chrome browser. The pipeline is working fine and the test scripts are working as expected in the pipeline.

However, during the run VSTest@2 task in the release pipeline, i'm getting a warning message.

```
[WARNING]: virtual void DevToolsClientImpl::AddListener(DevToolsEventListener *) subscribing a listener to the already connected DevToolsClient. Connection notification will not arrive.
```

This is not effecting my test result though. What does this error message mean? From what I gather, this is running a function even though it is already available.

If is it indeed a function, is it needed? Can it be disabled?

Many thanks

Comment: Did you get a resolution to this? Getting the same problem today - never happened previously, pipeline been running 12+ months now.

Comment: Unfortunately haven't

Comment: you can disable it by adding this option `options.add_argument("--log-level=1")`

Comment: Please can you advise where this option is added? Thanks

Comment: @soundwave I've tried adding this argument option in my Chrome driver but when i build and test in the release pipeline, the warning message is still being displayed

Comment: @captainjack Try with `log-level=3` and let me know

Comment: @DavidRedmayne You have to do 
`options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()` then `options.add_argument("--log-level=1")` and finally `driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(chromedriver_path), options=options)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently this was fixed in Chrome driver 111:

https://groups.google.com/g/chromedriver-users/c/W4HMXHAvyZU?pli=1

Comment: Updated Chrome driver fixed the issue